# Rybo switched the calculator keys!

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

I'm [Dave](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/50837/5373).

In revenge for my calculator key-switching prank, [Rybo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9802/rybo111) has performed a similar prank on me!

My calculator has the usual number keys, and keys for the usual four arithmetic operations:

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>  ; <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>÷</kbd>

All of the digits are where they should be, but two of the arithmetic-operation keys have been swapped. I don't know which two. Rybo says I'm only allowed to perform one operation - compute one sum using some of the ten digits and the four operation keys, as well as brackets <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> if necessary, any number of times - in such a way that the result of the calculation will tell me which two have been swapped.

**Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?**

<sub>Out-of-character disclaimer: I don't know the answer to this question.</sub>

Comment: Do the operations follow precedence?

Comment: @boboquack They're interpreted in the way a standard calculator would interpret them. Actually I'll make a slight edit to say brackets are also allowed to be used.

Comment: Congrats on the HNQ!

Comment: @boboquack I'm famous ;)

Comment: @rybo And I [announce](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer?userid=5373) your fame!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try (same as if operator precedence doesn't apply):

> `(1+2)-3`

Then:

> Switching `+,-`: `(1-2)+3=2`
>  Switching `+,x`: `(1x2)-3=-1`
>  Switching `+,÷`: `(1÷2)-3=-2.5`
>  Switching `-,x`: `(1+2)x3=9`
>  Switching `-,÷`: `(1+2)÷3=1`
>  Switching `x,÷`: `(1+2)-3=0`

---

**Note: [If anyone has more convoluted calculators, I'll post them as extra bonuses!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50851/rybo-switched-the-calculator-keys/50852?noredirect=1#comment155679_50852)**

Bonus: brackets not allowed, operator precedence applies:

> `1+2-3`

Then (assuming a 9-digit calculator):

> Switching `+,-`: `1-2+3=2`
>  Switching `+,x`: `1x2-3=-1`
>  Switching `+,÷`: `1÷2-3=-2.5`
>  Switching `-,x`: `1+2x3=7`
>  Switching `-,÷`: `1+2÷3=1.66666667`
>  Switching `x,÷`: `1+2-3=0`

Second bonus: brackets not allowed, operator precedence applies, calculator breaks on recurring decimals:

> `1+2-4`

Then:

> Switching `+,-`: `1-2+4=3`
>  Switching `+,x`: `1x2-4=-2`
>  Switching `+,÷`: `1÷2-4=-3.5`
>  Switching `-,x`: `1+2x4=9`
>  Switching `-,÷`: `1+2÷4=1.5`
>  Switching `x,÷`: `1+2-4=-1`

Third bonus: operator precedence doesn't apply, calculator breaks on any decimal:

> `8+4-4`

Then:

> Switching `+,-`: `8-4+4=8`
>  Switching `+,x`: `8x4-4=28`
>  Switching `+,÷`: `8÷4-4=-2`
>  Switching `-,x`: `8+4x4=48`
>  Switching `-,÷`: `8+4÷4=3`
>  Switching `x,÷`: `8+4-2=10`

Fourth bonus: operator precedence does apply, calculator breaks on any decimal:

> `8+4-4`

Then:

> Switching `+,-`: `8-4+4=8`
>  Switching `+,x`: `8x4-4=28`
>  Switching `+,÷`: `8÷4-4=-2`
>  Switching `-,x`: `8+4x4=24`
>  Switching `-,÷`: `8+4÷4=9`
>  Switching `x,÷`: `8+4-2=10`

Fifth bonus (@Penguino): operator precedence does apply, calculator breaks on any decimal, tens digit unreadable:

> `9+9-3`

Then:

> Switching `+,-`: `9-9+3=  3= ?3`
>  Switching `+,x`: `9x9-3= 78= ?8`
>  Switching `+,÷`: `9÷9-3=- 2=-?2`
>  Switching `-,x`: `9+9x3= 36= ?6`
>  Switching `-,÷`: `9+9÷3= 12= ?2`
>  Switching `x,÷`: `9+9-3= 15= ?5`

Sixth bonus (@Rubio): Operator precedence doesn't apply, decimals work, last 4 digits in display and also the top bar of any digit don't work (i.e. 1=7 and 4=9), 8 digit display + sign:

> `10000+729-1728`

Then:

> Switching `+,-`: `10000-729+1728=     10999=     X ????`
>  Switching `+,x`: `10000x729-1728=   7288272=   X28 ????`
>  Switching `+,÷`: `10000÷729-1728=-1714.2826=-X XXY.????`
>  Switching `-,x`: `10000+729x1728=  18539712= X 853 ????`
>  Switching `-,÷`: `10000+729÷1728= 6.2089120= 6.208 ????`
>  Switching `x,÷`: `10000+729-1728=      9001=       ????`

Seventh bonus (@QPaysTaxes): operator precedence applies backwards, calculator breaks on any decimal:

> `8+4-2`

Then:

> Switching `+,-`: `8-4+2=2`
>  Switching `+,x`: `8x4-2=16`
>  Switching `+,÷`: `8÷4-2=8`
>  Switching `-,x`: `8+4x2=24`
>  Switching `-,÷`: `8+4÷2=6`
>  Switching `x,÷`: `8+4-2=10`

Comment: Well, that was easier than I'd imagined.

Comment: I hate when my calculator breaks on decimals.

Comment: If anyone has more convoluted calculators, I'll post them as extra bonuses!

Comment: @boboquack For my calculator operator precedence does apply and it breaks on any decimal. Unfortunately the 7-segment LED display for the second-most digit to the right is damaged (it only shows the two left-most vertical segments and the middle horizontal segment) so, for example, I can't distinguish 10 from 20. Can you help?

Comment: @Penguino Done! I've assumed (like on my own calculator) that the negative sign displays on the leftmost 7-segment LED, and ignored the LED second from the right completely

Comment: @boboquack Excellent. That saves me having to ask about my other calculator where the 10's digit is even more damaged.

Comment: On small comment. In third and forth bonus parts you got `8x4-4=20`. That's not right. This does not break the approach. It's just confusing. :) Also, the same bonuses 3 & 4 state `8+4-2` but the examples shown use `8+4-4`.

Comment: @Marius Thanks! Didn't spot that! (I'd just got online when I'd posted, still a bit bleary-headed)

Comment: My calculator's LCD display is badly damaged.  The rightmost 4 digits don't display at all. For all remaining digits, the top segment is stuck on, so 1 and 7 look identical as do 4 and 9.

Comment: @Rubio
 All done!

Comment: My calculator's battery is flat so it can't display any digits at all. But I know the buttons that were swapped are looser than the other two. But I only get to mash my palm against the keypad once...

Comment: My calculator was made by a first-year CS student in a hurry to get the project turned in, and does operator precedence backwards. (i.e. `8*4-4 == 8*(4-4) == 0`). (I have no idea if this will make things harder or not)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Does your calculator support decimals?

Comment: @boboquack If you use them, you're straying into [nasal demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) territory. (in other words, no.)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Done! Bonus - no negative numbers!

Comment: Nice! What strategy are you using to figure these out? Or is it mostly trial/error/intuition?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yeah, just that (unfortunately).

Comment: The calculator displays the digits in an unknown language (1 might be # and 2 might be &, etc), precedence applies, calculator breaks on anything over 100.